# merge classic (email/password) login with facebook login

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website that has classic email/password login and also facebook-login. I keep a field  (namely `fb_connect(TINY_INT(1))` )in the database if user anyway installed the app to login with facebook, the `fb_connect` field will be 1.

I use both facebook javascript SDK and facebook PHP SDK like in the github examples.

So, when the user uses classic email/password login, the system checks whether `fb_connect` is set to 1. I want to use PHP SDK that'll automatically go to `$login_url` of facebook and redirected back to system.

However, I have different kinds of `redirect_uri` s. I need to be able to make redirection in different pages.

Anyone come up with a solution to that problem ?

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to store the page address in the php session where you want to redirect after successful login in facebook.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['state']))
          {
               $redirect_to = $_SESSION['redirect_url'] ? $_SESSION['redirect_url'] : 'index.php';
               header ("Location: $redirect_to");
          }
```

Hopefully this will help you.